# how to select values from csv file and write it to another csv file using python

Tags: python, list, csv, mod-rewrite

I have a python script that read from CSV file and check if the records meet the conditions.

- row[0] ==> Date type Date
- row[10] ==> wind speed type float
- row[11] ==> fog type boolean

these are the columns that i need to select  and write the result into another csv file.

the problem is that the system create the second csv  file but **EMPTY**

and the system display this error :

```
append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

but i need to assign the 3 lists into one variable list  called **result**

where the error in my code?

## code:

```
import csv

mydelimeter = csv.excel()
mydelimeter.delimiter=";"
myfile = open("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv")

# read the first line in the opened file ==> Header
myfile.readline()


myreader=csv.reader(myfile,mydelimeter)
result=[]

'''
create a variable that handle values of the 3 fields ==> Date - fastest5secwindspeed - fog
 and display the result where  
     fog ==> Yes    and highest speed  more than 10.
'''

for index ,row in enumerate(myreader):
    try:
        '''
        check if the values in the fog colums is == Yes 
        if ok 
        check if the column of the "fastwindspeed" is  empty ==>  raise Exception
        check if the value in column of the "fastwindspeed" is < 10.0 ==>  raise Exception

        else  print the results
        '''
        if row[11] =="Yes":
            if row[10] in (None, ""):
                raise Exception( "this Record has empty value" )
            if float(row[10]) < 10.0:
                raise Exception( 'the wind speed  is below 10 mph in ' + row[0] )            
            print(row[0],row[10],row[11])
            '''
            append the result into a list in order to use it in the writing of the new csv file  
            '''
            result.append(row[0],row[10],row[11])
    except Exception as e:
        print("{}:{}".format(index ,e))

with open("C:/Users/test/Documents/Python_Projects/rduSpeedFog.csv", "w") as f:
    fwriter=csv.writer(f,mydelimeter)
    for row in result:
        fwriter.writerows(row[0],row[10],row[11])
    print("Writing Complete")
f.close()
```

Comment: instead of `result.append(row[0],row[10],row[11])` use `result.append(row[0]) result.append(row[10]) result.append(row[11]))`

Comment: i tried your answer but the format content of the second file was a mess

Comment: Why is this question tagged as **mod-rewrite** ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the documentation on the list.append() function](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> list.append(x)
>
> Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].

The function is designed to accept one thing as a parameter (in this case, `x`), but you're passing it three separate things, hence the error:

> append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

You should pass it values one-at-time, or even better, do something like:

```
l = []
values = [foo[0], foo[1], foo[2]]
for v in values:
    l.append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

First add the values to the `result` list as a list or a tuple

```
result.append([row[0],row[10],row[11]])
#or
result.append((row[0],row[10],row[11]))
```

Then, when you'll be writing them to the other file by doing

```
for row in result:
    fwriter.writerow(row)
#or instead just
fwriter.writerows(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to append to `result` one row with the 3 fields `row[0]`, `row[10]` and row[11]. 
So, put them in a list and append the list to result:

```
new_row = [row[0],row[10],row[11]]
result.append(new_row)
```

When writing to the csv file, you want to use `writerow()` to write one of your new rows at a time:

```
for row in result:
    fwriter.writerow(row)
```

or, to write all the rows in result at once:

```
fwriter.writerows(result)
```